# Obtaining the location of places on facebook and integrating it into window phone app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to obtain information of a users current location I already have the users latitude and longitude what I want to know is are there any businesses (restaurants, clothing stores ect.) in that area. I was just looking at the open graph api and It says that you can search over all public objects in the social graph with https://graph.facebook.com/search. We support searchs for the following types of objects: places https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place but the ones I really want to use type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 does not work in the API Explorer could anyone tell me what might be the problem and how do I use this in a windows phone 7 app? Links, code snippets, blog post, ebooks, Other web services that would allow me I could send lat and long and will return the location or businesses anything will be very helpfull thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

This query should give you the results you need.

Comment: so what's the deal with object location: type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 why does this one not work? That is what one I really what to use I dont want to have to enter a keyword like - coffee.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 try this. Your type is wrong in the current query.